# MongoDB installation hell

Tags: linux, mongodb, service, centos, systemd

I'm having a dilemma here. I was required to (attempt to) upgrade MongoDB on my CentOS 7 server from 2.6.X to 3.0+. I tried following the basic guide from Mongo (replacing the binaries directly) and this worked perfectly well... in local. On the server my MongoDB service is totally flipping out and I have no idea. And on top of that Mongo Shell is still at 2.6 somehow XD

systemctl status mongo* reveals this catastrophe:

```
root@staging:~# systemctl status mongo*
● mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 一 2016-01-25 16:57:13 CST; 18h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

1月 25 16:57:13 staging systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
1月 25 16:57:13 staging runuser[5310]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
1月 25 16:57:13 staging runuser[5310]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
1月 25 16:57:13 staging mongod[5301]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
1月 25 16:57:13 staging systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
1月 25 16:57:13 staging systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
1月 25 16:57:13 staging systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
1月 25 16:57:13 staging systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
1月 26 11:03:04 staging systemd[1]: Stopped SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
1月 26 11:04:52 staging systemd[1]: Stopped SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..

● mongos.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 一 2016-01-25 15:46:20 CST; 20h ago

1月 25 15:46:20 staging systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
1月 25 15:46:20 staging mongos[2712]: /usr/bin/mongos: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such f... directory
1月 25 15:46:20 staging systemd[1]: mongos.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
1月 25 15:46:20 staging systemd[1]: Failed to start High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
1月 25 15:46:20 staging systemd[1]: Unit mongos.service entered failed state.
1月 25 15:46:20 staging systemd[1]: mongos.service failed.
1月 25 16:04:23 staging systemd[1]: Stopped High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
1月 26 11:18:04 staging systemd[1]: Stopped mongos.service.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again, as always.

Comment: `staging mongos[2712]: /usr/bin/mongos: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such f... directory`

Comment: Yes... I have no idea how to fix it though. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This was ultimately solved by `yum remove mongo*` followed by manually removing ANYTHING referring to Mongo in any way (found using `locate mongo*`). Then adding an up to date Mongo repo and installing v3.2.1 via yum (contrary to the more commonplace suggestion from MongoDB to simply replace the binaries directly).